# python interpreter running shutdown code when I don't want it to

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess

I'm using Python 3. I'm still learning but am, let's say, an intermediate at other programming languages. I'm building a simple GUI that just does simple things for now but will add on more things as I go. I've got some success. Then I had an idea, to have a function (or whatever it's called in Python) to run an external script, stored in my script folder. So I wrote this...

```
def runscript(scriptname):
    from subprocess import call
    call(['scripts/'+scriptname])
```

Then later on in my code I have this...

```
sdb = Button(topbar, text="Shutdown", command= runscript("shutdown.sh"), font=("Helvetica", 20), width=18)
```

shutdown.sh is a simple script that does what you might expect it to.

Now whenever I run the python script with python3 MyScript.py the machine instantly shuts down! I obviously only want it to shut down when I click the Shutdown button. From reading I gather it's to do with the fact that Python executes every line as it goes. So I don't understand why there are plenty of examples around on the internet for functions that will shutdown your PC, whereas my more general script-running code doesn't work in any useful way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write the code `runscript("shutdown.sh")`, what should it do?

Obviously, the answer is that it should call the `runscript` function and pass it the argument `"shutdown.sh"`.

So, when you write the code `command=runscript("shutdown.sh")`, what should it do?

Do you see the problem? You're executing the `runscript` function, and passing the result of that function to the `command` attribute. Instead, the `command` attribute takes a *reference* to a callable function. Since you are trying to pass in an explicit argument, one way to accomplish that is with lambda:

```
sdb = Button(..., command=lambda script="shutdown.sh": runscript(script))
```

Some people prefer [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) over lambda:

```
sdb = Button(..., command=functools.partial(runscript, "shutdown.sh"))
```